# p5.speech set default voice is not working

Tags: p5.js

Hello I am working with p5.speech and I have set in my code a default voice to an english voice like so:

```
var speech = new p5.Speech('Kate');
```

My computer default language is Italian, and everything works as it should. I hear the english voice. I tested it on a friend computer and he gets his Spanish default speaking voice. How is this possible? Do I need some more settings?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using the setLang() method listed in the [reference page](https://idmnyu.github.io/p5.js-speech/#reference)?

Comment: Tried that as well, but with no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Voices available to different browsers, operating systems, individual computers are vastly different. Your friend's computer probably does not have a voice named Kate.

These are voices available to Chrome on my Win10 machine.
[image: Chrome-win10]

These are voices available to Edge on my Win10 machine.
[image: Edge-win10]

These are voices available to Chrome on my MacBook Pro.
[image: Chrome-mac]

It's less likely that people will have a specific English voice named Kate; it's more likely that people will have at least one en-US voice. The following code can choose an English (United States) voice for you.

```js
var speech = new p5.Speech();
speech.setLang("en-US");
```

---

**Demo:**

[https://glitch.com/~p5-speech-setlang-setvoice](https://glitch.com/%7Ep5-speech-setlang-setvoice)

A demo for you to try different combinations of `setLang()` and `setVoice()`

---

**My observations:**

1. Voices available depend on the browser you use. For example, I have 21 voices in Chrome and 6 in Edge.
2. There are two related functions: `setVoice()` and `setLang()`. They digest different arguments.
3. `setLang()` will try to choose a voice in the language you want if you have never called `setVoice()`. If you have called `setVoice()` once, `setLang()` won't be able to change voice for you anymore.

`setLang()`
For example:

```js
setLang("it-IT")
setLang("en-US")
setLang("en-GB")
setLang("es-ES")
```

`setVoice()`
For example:

```js
setVoice("Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)")
setVoice("Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)")
setVoice("Google US English")
setVoice("Google UK English Female")
```

References: [BCP-47 code for languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/commerce-server/ee825488(v=cs.20)) | [p5.speech reference](https://idmnyu.github.io/p5.js-speech/#reference)